# Switching between Master and Detail on smaller screens?

Tags: responsive-design, master-details

I have played with a simple draft of displaying master view (normally a table) and detail view (normally a single record).

On bigger screens it may look like this:

[image: bigger screen]

But the challenge is to make a good UX when it comes to smaller screens. Is this a viable option? Or is there a better way to do this?

[Live example](https://tmpl2.go4webdev.org)

[image: small screen]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not only the change in screen size, but you are also changing the typology of the elements.

On large screens, they are labels with icons, while on the small ones, they change to buttons, so they should have the characteristics of such:

[image]